# pig - split, lack of default or if/else

Tags: apache-pig

Since there is no else or default statements in pig split operation what would be the most elegant way to do the following? I'm not a big fan of having to copy paste code.

```
SPLIT rawish_data
    INTO good_rawish_data IF (
    (uid > 0L) AND
    (value1 > 0) AND
    (value1 < 100) AND
    (value1 IS NOT NULL) AND
    (value2 > 0L) AND
    (value2 < 200L) AND
    (value3 >= 0) AND
    (value3 <= 300)),

    bad_rawish_data IF (NOT (
    (uid > 0L) AND
    (value1 > 0) AND
    (value1 < 100) AND
    (value1 IS NOT NULL) AND
    (value2 > 0L) AND
    (value2 < 200L) AND
    (value3 >= 0) AND
    (value3 <= 300)));
```

I would like to do something like

```
SPLIT data
    INTO good_data IF (
    (value > 0)),
    good_data_big_values IF (
    (value > 100)),
    bad_data DEFAULT;
```

Is anything like this possible in anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is. Checking out the docs for [`SPLIT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#SPLIT), you want to use `OTHERWISE`. For example:

```
SPLIT data
    INTO good_data IF (
    (value > 0)),
    good_data_big_values IF (
    (value > 100)),
    bad_data OTHERWISE;
```

So you almost got it. :)

**NOTE:** `SPLIT` can put a single row into both `good_data` and `good_data_big_values` if, for example, `value` was 150. I don't know if this is what you want, but you should be aware of it regardless.  This also means that `bad_data` will only contain rows where `value` is 0 or less.

Comment: Important note:  `bad_data` will NOT contain rows where value is null!  You need to specifically check for null or those rows will be dropped in this expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an IsGood() UDF where all the conditions are checked. Then your pig is simply

```
SPLIT data
    INTO good_data IF (IsGood(data))
         good_data_big_values IF (IsGood(data) AND value > 100)),
         bad_data IF (NOT IsGood(data))
;
```

Another option might be to use a [macro](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#macros)

Comment: If you use a `recently` checked out Pig from trunk, then using macros is an option, otherwise you may run into troubles. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3239

Comment: Are you sure you can use `IsGood(data)` like that?  Wouldn't you have to pass each (relevant) field like `IsGood(value, uid, etc.)`?