# PIG script IF ELSE statement

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Does pig script support if-else statement

here is what I want to do:

if($NAME=='Joey')
    Do something
else
    Do something

is that doable?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669522/is-there-any-conditional-if-like-operator-in-apache-pig

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913764/pig-split-lack-of-default-or-if-else

Answer (score 4):

Its Called a "Bincond" Operator

Statements Like:

```
(Price > 75 ? 'High':'Low')
```

are also valid

For Handling Null Records:

```
((Name is null or IsEmpty(Name)) ? {('unknown')} : Name)
```

Use them in a foreach statement with alias along other fields i.e:

```
A = load 'x/y/Price.csv' as (Name, Product, Price);
B = foreach A generate Name, Product, Price, (Price > 75 ? 'High':'Low') as Indicator;

dump B;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the conditional operator. For example

```
(Name=='Joey'? 'Yes':'No')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (I started pig latin yesterday), pig doesn't have if-else or for statement, you have to use python or java to do so, see here : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch09.html